# Null value in column "logit" violates not-null constraint

Tags: sql, case, sqldatatypes, greenplum

I am using Greenplum (based on PostgreSQL 8.2.15) and my update command:

```
update table01
set logit=
case
when sex = '03' then
logit+0.5*0.8
when sex = '@0' then
logit+0.5*0.2
when sex = '02' then
logit+0.5*0.4
when sex = 'N' then
logit+0.5*(-1.6)
when sex = '01' then
logit+0.5*(-0.4)
end;
```

It offered me an error:

> null value in column "logit" violates not-null constraint

The `"logit"` column type is double precision and except when `sex = 'N'` returns no rows, other conditions have ones.

I have checked other answers concerned about this error but did not get help yet. Why does this occur and how to fix it?

Comment: Aside, Greenplum is not Postgres by a long shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set the `update` to match the `case` statements that have values:

```
update table01
    set logit = (case when sex = '03' then logit+0.5*0.8
                      when sex = '@0' then logit+0.5*0.2
                      when sex = '02' then logit+0.5*0.4
                      when sex = 'N' then logit+0.5*(-1.6)
                      when sex = '01' then logit+0.5*(-0.4)
                 end)
    where sex in ('03', '@0', '02', 'N', '1');
```

Alternatively, you can keep the value the same explicitly in the `set`:

```
update table01
    set logit = (case when sex = '03' then logit+0.5*0.8
                      when sex = '@0' then logit+0.5*0.2
                      when sex = '02' then logit+0.5*0.4
                      when sex = 'N' then logit+0.5*(-1.6)
                      when sex = '01' then logit+0.5*(-0.4)
                      else logic
                 end);
```

The first version is more efficient.  The second is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ELSE` branch in you [`CASE` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) to catch everything else. It defaults to NULL when missing.

Add an `ELSE` branch to `CASE` to fix it.
Or a `WHERE` clause to your `UPDATE` to only update rows that won't turn NULL.